# Database design for a form builder in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, forms, database-design, database-schema

Currently I am working on a form builder,

the user can add input box with different name into the form.

Notice that the form will be stored as HTML code, so the only concern is the input box name storage and submit form value

Now I have draft a table like this

```
form
-----
id

inputs
------
form_id
name

values
-------
input_id
value
```

One problem I can think of is the data type of value, 
the above design works only if the value is text / textarea

How to handle if the input box is file upload / radio / select?

so are there are  Any better design,

thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to store element type also. according to the element type,find out which html element it is and render this

Answer (score 1):

You will need an extra table for radio and select, since it has multiple rows for one `<input>` field.

Don't forget about optional things like id=, name=, style=, class=, etc.

I predict that your finished product will be as clumsy to use as typing the form elements by hand.